# Facebook wants an iPhone app ID, but I don't have one

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm making an app that uses Facebook APIs. Facebook wants me to enter the App Store ID when I'm setting up my app on developers.facebook.com. I am still working on my app and am nowhere near ready to release it on the App Store. Is there a way to get an app ID that it will accept so I can test my code before releasing it?

I found a similar question from 2011 where people said to just use another app's ID or enter "0". Neither of those work. Someone said to create it on iTunes Connect and just not upload it; I got an app ID from that, but Facebook says it's invalid, which doesn't surprise me since I don't see how they could check that unless I publish the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Facebook App ID is not the same as the App Store ID. You can get one at developers.facebook.com. Facebook does allow you to set your App Store ID in your FB App's settings, but it is optional.

Comment: You're right! It isn't optional if you want to put it on the App Center, but I was trying to do so because the login kept failing and saying that I hadn't set up my app correctly. The only reason the login wasn't working was because I was using an account not designated as a tester on Facebook. Hopefully others see this before they waste their time like I did. Thank you.